# Layout gets cut off when rotating to left

Tags: android, android-layout, android-framelayout, android-4.4-kitkat

I have the following layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:keepScreenOn="true"
>


<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/camera_preview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/menus_layer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:visibility="gone">

</FrameLayout>

<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/orientation_layer"
    android:visibility="gone">

    <include layout="@layout/layer_orientation"/>

</FrameLayout>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/interruption_menu"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Interruption"/>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/action_menu"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Action"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

and layer_orientation.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/check_orientation"
android:gravity="center"
android:layout_gravity="center"
android:visibility="visible"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="100dp"
android:padding="5dp"
android:background="@android:color/holo_red_light"
>

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_always_landscape_portrait"/>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/please_check_orientation"
    android:layout_gravity="fill" />
</LinearLayout>
```

The activity that holds the layout has its orientation set to landscape. Using an OrientationEventListener I want to show and rotate accordingly the orientation_layer. Something like:

```
private final static int THRESHOLD = 45;
private final static int NORMAL = 270;
mOrientationEventListener = new OrientationEventListener(mContext, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_UI) {
        @Override
        public void onOrientationChanged(int orientation) {
            if (mCallback != null) {
                if (orientation <= NORMAL + THRESHOLD && orientation >= NORMAL - THRESHOLD)
                    mCallback.hideOrientationLayer();
                else {
                    int rot = (NORMAL - orientation - THRESHOLD) / 90;
                    if (rot >= 0)
                        rot = (rot + 1) * 90;
                    else
                        rot = rot * 90;
                    mCallback.showOrientationLayer(rot);
                }
            }
        }
    };
    @Override
    public void showOrientationLayer(int rotation) {
        mOrientationLayer.setRotation(rotation);
        mOrientationLayer.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

    @Override
    public void hideOrientationLayer() {
        mOrientationLayer.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
```

If I rotate the device to right, the framelayout is displayed ok, but if I rotate it to the left, only half of the layout is displayed, the other half is cut off. Here are some screenshots: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/ypu6txrwpve27ud/Lv_9lTJybA
And an Android Studio test project: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/f5kiaw7y5ueb0zk/FASOGh54SD

After some testing, I concluded that this manifests only on KitKat.

Does anyone have some ideas about what could be wrong? Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is the values of NORMAL and THRESHOLD

Comment: try to remove android:layout_gravity="fill" and change android:layout_height="100dp" to wrap_content

Comment: I edited the question, and I added those 2 values.

Comment: can you apply what I wrote in the last comment and tell the results

Comment: I just did, but it made no difference :(

Comment: I created an android project and exactly added you code and it worked just fine. no cuts!!!

Comment: What device did you use for testing? I used Nexus 7 2013 and Nexus 4, both with Android 4.4.2 running on ART, and Samsung Galaxy S with Android 4.4.2 with Dalvik. Unfortunately, the only non-KitKat device that I had was a LG Optimus Sol, which displayed a corrupted image, due to the camera preview layer below, I think...

Comment: Mine is Samsung S Dous :) with 4.0.4 but I am not sure that this is a device related problem. because I don't show or hide the other frame layouts and there isnt another work on the activity. what I am saying that code for this is perfectly fine.

Comment: listen, create a new project and only include the code you posted here. and check the results.

Comment: I made a small project that reproduces the problem. Here it is: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/f5kiaw7y5ueb0zk/FASOGh54SD

Comment: your demo doesn't work.

Comment: what's the problem with it?

Comment: compilation errors. I fixed those. but on run can't run the activity. why your classes is not in src folder

Comment: It's an Android Studio project. Sorry for not mentioning that before.